# The color of the bottom with madrid theme

Tags: beamer

I'm using the following codes

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
 \usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % rendre l'écriture math plus beau
    %---------------------------  
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\usepackage%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %-----accent
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut 
          poser des problème
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
     \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
     %-----
       \usepackage{pifont} %bouni
    %-----
    \usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
  \newcommand{\cadre}[1]{
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{7pt}
  \begin{center}
    \shadowbox{#1}
     \end{center}}
   %--------------------
     \usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
   %----------pabox----------
   \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

   \newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=bg,
     colframe=blue!75!black,
     fonttitle=\bfseries,
     coltitle=blue!75!black,
    colbacktitle=bg,
    enhanced,
     attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
     title=#2,
      #1}
    %--------------------
      %--------------------
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%il s'agit d'une frame de passage d'une section vers une 
    autre%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     % Delete this, if you do not want the table of contents to pop up at
      % the beginning of each subsection:
       %------------------------\AtBeginSection[]--------------------------- 
      -------------------------------

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
     -----------
  %------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------------- 
   -----------------------------
     \AtBeginSubsection[]
     {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
     \transsplitverticalout
   \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
   \end{frame}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}% If you don't want them to affect the 
       slide 
 number
     }
   %------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    ------- 
       ---
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%\mode%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \mode<presentation>

      \usetheme{Madrid}

     %%%------------------footline--------
     \setbeamertemplate{footline}
      {
      \leavevmode%
     \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in 
   head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
     \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title 
       in 
     head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
          \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
       \end{beamercolorbox}}%
       \vskip0pt%
      }
     %%%%%astuces%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % supprimer trace de la sourie
      %\beamertemplateboldcenterframetitle  % le titre des frame centré
      %\setbeamertemplate{headline}{} % supprimer le headline
     %%%%%%newcommand%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %------------------------------------------------
    \definecolor{studentbrown}{RGB}{124,71,50}

      \BeforeBeginEnvironment{lemma}{%
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=studentbrown}
     \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=studentbrown!20!white}
       }
     \AfterEndEnvironment{lemma}{
     \setbeamercolor{block title} 
    {use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
       \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block 
        title,bg=block 
       title.bg!10!bg}
      }
     %------------------------------------------------
      \BeforeBeginEnvironment{corollary}{
      \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=orange!50!white}
   \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=orange!30!white}
     }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{corollary}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title} 
  {use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block 
   title.bg!50!bg, fg=black}
     }
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin document 
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{document}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The 
   essential 
  numerical range and the Olsen problem} %\emph{}
  \author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{frame}

 \end{frame}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

When I compilate I obtain

[image]

However I want to obtain

[image]

Comment: Your MWE does not compile, there are several lines in your preamble which should be commented out

Comment: @samcarter Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Basically everywhere. You must not have line breaks in comments without repeating %

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the colour of the footline with

```
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue}
```

Some other comments:

- If you have line breaks within your comments you **must** put a % in front of each line. Some of your line breaks cause compilation errors, others incorrect output on your slides
- `\thispagestyle{empty}` is not very beamerish, I would use the `plain` frame option instead.
- same for `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}`, you can use `noframenumbering` instead.
- better use `\title` and `\author` before `\begin{document}`, then you will get reasonable pdf meta information.

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{   
    \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
        \transsplitverticalout
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue}

\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The 
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What are the codes that you have added?

Comment: @Student See the first 3 lines of my answer

Comment: This packages `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} `
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

`\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math `?

Comment: @Student Are in general OK, but not necessary for the example above

Comment: Please my field of reasearch is mathematics. Is there a packages to improve my beamer? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please for someone who study mathematics it this package `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`  not necessary? Because I remark that you have deleted it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Student This is just a matter of taste. I deleted everything not necessary to  answer the question because all the missing comments produced too many errors to fix. (my personal opinion: I find different fonts for math and text ugly)