# frametitle with the new colors

Tags: beamer, color

I want to use madrid theme and I want to achieve the horizontal shading effect in the frametitle with the colors like the following picture

[image]

I try as follows by using the following two answers ([a1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459331/the-color-of-the-bottom-with-madrid-theme), [a2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226691/how-can-i-have-a-horizontally-shaded-frametitle-in-beamer)):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{   
    \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
        \transsplitverticalout
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%            \hspace*{3em}
%            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
%            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
        \end{beamercolorbox}%        
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=black}

\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The 
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}

   \useoutertheme{shadow}
      \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{shadings}

    \colorlet{titleleft}{red!70!black}
     \colorlet{titleright}{white}

     \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white}

   \makeatletter
   \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright] 
    {beamer@frametitleshade} 
    {\paperheight}{%
     color(0pt)=(titleleft);
   color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{linear relation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However I remark that I loss my previous botom

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific: the colour of which elements do you want to change? The code you show cannot reproduce the image, there is no frametitle, no blocks, a different footline.... How are the colours you want defined? What are their RGB values?

Comment: There is no need to start all your question titles with the word question. If they would  not be questions, they would not be asked as questions, would they?

Comment: You also might want to disclose where the code you show is from... The licence of this site is "cc by-sa 3.0 with **attribution required.**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @samcarter Please see my edit. I want the color in the bottom and in the head when I use madrid presentation will be like the picture thank you

Comment: The linked question shows you how to add a gradient to the frametitle. I have already shown you how to change the colours in the footer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459331/the-color-of-the-bottom-with-madrid-theme

Comment: Please what are the names of the color in the picture? Thank you very much.

Comment: Determining the names of the colours you want is not a latex problem However you could look them up in the documentation of the `xcolor` package. Thanks a lot for ignoring all my other comments.

Comment: I don't ignore your comments. You helped me in so many questions and thank you very much.

Comment: You ignored my comment asking you to disclose the source of your code.

Comment: I'm very sorry.

Comment: @samcarter When I use the codes of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226691/how-can-i-have-a-horizontally-shaded-frametitle-in-beamer I loss the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pay attention to the order in which you make combine the modifications. Your custom footline definition should be after you load other themes.

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=blue]{structure}

%------------------------\AtBeginSubsection[]----------------------
\AtBeginSubsection[]{   
    \begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering,plain]{Outline}
        \transsplitverticalout
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}



\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=yellow!30!white,fg=blue!30!black}
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{bg=blue!30!black,fg=white}

\title[The essential numerical range and the Olsen problem]{The 
essential numerical range and the Olsen problem}
\author[{Student} (University of ....)]{Student}

   \useoutertheme{shadow}
      \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{shadings}

    \colorlet{titleleft}{yellow!30!white}
     \colorlet{titleright}{blue!30!black}

     \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=blue!30!black}

   \makeatletter
   \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright] 
    {beamer@frametitleshade} 
    {\paperheight}{%
     color(0pt)=(titleleft);
   color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)}
  \makeatother

%-----------------------------footline-----------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
%            \hspace*{3em}
%            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{page number in head/foot}%
%            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{3em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
        \end{beamercolorbox}%        
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
}  

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{linear relation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Student It would still be nice if you would disclose where the code fragments in your question come from!

Comment: @Student I'm very disappointed. You had several hours, but did not edit your question to include the source of the code

Comment: I'm very sorry because I just understand you now. Thank you very much. Please see my edit.

Comment: I hope that you find my edit good because I'm not very well in English and some times I find some difficulties in understand somes words. Please I'm very sorry.

Comment: @Student Thanks for the edit! If you are not sure if you understand something it is better to ask instead of ignoring.

Comment: I don't ignore. I thought that you ask me to learn more about the codes. Thank you again for your great help.